# SELECT only the rows with a unique value on certain columns

Tags: sql-server-2012, select, distinct

I have a table with multiple records by each employee, i need to find all the records by employee where any of the columns values changes. for example i have the following data for George:

| **HOME** | **CURRENT** | **EFFECTIVEDATE** | **NOTTOEXCEEDDATE** | **FLAG** | **GRADE** | **POSITION** | **LASTPAYPERIODPAID** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 610422 | NULL | NULL | N | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 610422 | NULL | NULL | N | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 610422 | NULL | NULL | N | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 610422 | NULL | NULL | N | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |

How do i get the following result data set ?

| **HOME** | **CURRENT** | **EFFECTIVEDATE** | **NOTTOEXCEEDDATE** | **FLAG** | **GRADE** | **POSITION** | **LASTPAYPERIODPAID** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GEORGE | 610124 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 14 | ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 630100 | 11/10/2019 | 11/6/2021 | Y | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |
| GEORGE | 610422 | 610422 | NULL | NULL | N | 15 | SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT |

so far i can only get the result data set by doing a Select Distinct without the LAST_PAY_PERIOD_PAID column. as soon as i add this column i get the first table all over again.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your problem

Distinct produces exactly what you want

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
[HOME]
, [CURRENT]
, [EFFECTIVEDATE]
, [NOTTOEXCEEDDATE]
, [FLAG]
, [GRADE]
, [POSITION]
, [LASTPAYPERIODPAID]
FROM Table1
```

Result

```
HOME    CURRENT EFFECTIVEDATE   NOTTOEXCEEDDATE     FLAG        GRADE   POSITION    LASTPAYPERIODPAID
GEORGE  610124  630100          11/10/2019          11/6/2021   Y       14          ACCOUNTANT
GEORGE  610422  610422          (null)              (null)      N       15          SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT
GEORGE  610422  630100          11/10/2019           11/6/2021  Y       14          ACCOUNTANT
GEORGE  610422  630100          11/10/2019           11/6/2021  Y       15          SUPERVISOR ACCOUNTANT
```

George has two current numbers, that is why i don't get your result

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f5920/1